# How to bind a property to the background of a row

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind a property to the background of a row...

The goal is to set a color randomly to rows where values 'msgid' are empty (with +- 10 RGB-codes I have).

Note: Why do I have to set INotifyPropertyChanged anyway ?
I don't understand that...I don't need the set part !?

What I have:

In my window class:

```
OtherClass viewModel = new OtherClass();
this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Then in OtherClass:

```
 class OtherClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    Brush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);

    public Brush RowColor
    {

        get { return color; }
        set
        {
            color = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("RowColor");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }


}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="536" Width="659" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Icon="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/dtc.ico">

<Window.Resources>

    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="SmsData" XPath="/response">

    </XmlDataProvider>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid Width="642">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SmsData}, XPath=conv/sms}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dataGrid1" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="-5,13,4,244" BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" IsEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=msgid}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=imsgid}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=recipient}" Width="100"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=datetime}" Width="120" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding XPath=message}" Width="225" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>


        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type  DataGridRow}">


               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=msgid}" Value="{x:Null}">


                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RowColor}" />

                    </DataTrigger>


            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
    <RichTextBox Height="122" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,311,0,0" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="228" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
    <Menu Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="645">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu">
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Logs" />
        <MenuItem Header="Help" />
    </Menu>
    <Image Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-10,251,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/send%20sms.jpg" />
    <Button Content="send messge" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="402,454,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="228" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Label Content="Number:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,311,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Image Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,252,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="338" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/line.jpg" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,316,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.rowColor}"

Try setting that on your Setter. Without the entire xaml, it is hard to tell.

Comment: does your class implement INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rowColor property does not raise the PropertyChanged event.

Implement INotifyPropertychanged on the OtherClass and raise the PropertyChanged event in the setter of the rowColor property.

BTW: Please stick to the way Microsoft names properties: RowColor instead of rowColor. This prevent confusion.

Comment: I don't know if I get it...what I changed (and not working):

(1) class OtherClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
(2) this.OnPropertyChanged("RowColor"); (within set (get/set))
(3) function public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

(3) XAML stayed the same (exept namechange to rowColor => RowColor :-))

Comment: Please put the exact code in the question, so we can read it and answer.

Comment: If its a `DataTrigger`, the binding for `RowColor` should be a `Two-Way Binding Mode` or the property changing wouldn't affect the `DataTrigger`, because it would be considered `One-Way`.

Comment: Did=> Value="{Binding Path=RowColor, Mode=TwoWay} ...nothing happend :(

Comment: @user1913808 - the DataTrigger should be nested in a `<Style.Triggers>` element